# Problema en Ref de Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, backend, referencias

En mi backend tengo 3 modelos, user, admin y operator, en admin y operator guardo mis usuarios correpondientes y en el modelo user estoy guardando todos los usuarios admins y operators pero unicamente su username, password y el rol, sea admin u operator, el problema es que solo me esta guardando un solo registro y no hace mas nada

**user_model**

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
admins: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'admin'
},
operators: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'operator'
}

})
```

**user_controller**

```
//READ ALL ADMINS
user_controler.getAdmins = async (req, res) => {
    
    user_model.find().populate({path: 'admins'}).exec((error, admins) => {
        if(error){
            res.status(500).send({
                message: 'Error en la peticion'
            })
        } else {
            if(!admins || admins.length == 0){
                res.status(404).send({
                    message: 'No existe ningun usuario registrado'
                })
            } else {
                res.status(200).send({ admins })
            }
        }
    })
    }

//READ ALL OPERATORS
user_controler.getOperators = async (req, res) => {

    user_model.find().populate({path: 'operators'}).exec((error, operators) => {
        if(error){
            res.status(500).send({
                message: 'Error en la peticion'
            })
        } else {
            if(!operators || operators.length == 0){
                res.status(404).send({
                    message: 'No existe ningun usuario registrado'
                })
            } else {
                res.status(200).send({ operators })
            }
        }
    })
    }
```

**Respuesta de la consulta**
[image: Respuesta de la consulta]

> Deberia devolver 2 usuarios administradores y 3 operadores que son los que tengo almacenados en mi BD

Agradeceria la ayuda, gracias! <3